# How to get identity using Scope_Identity() in SqlDataAdapter's RowUpdated Method

Tags: c#, sql-server

I know other alternative *@@identity* and *Ident_Current('')* but trigger is executing after inserting a new record in table. So I am using *Scope_Identity()*. Is there any other solution?

Comment: Did you try using the output clause?

Comment: Is the source a DataTable.  Can use DataTable methods to get changes.

Comment: @ZoharPeled,can you give some example of that?

Comment: @jdweng,I tried,it is not possible by getchanges method

Comment: I read some blogs and want to share this: I am performing these by SqlDataAdapter.Update(table) method and using transaction for that.As SqlDataAdapter.update() using it's own scope to insert,I am not getting identity value on that,whereas  @@identity and Ident_Current gives value.

Comment: Sorry, but using an output clause will not help in this situation.

Comment: What about row RowChanged Event?

Comment: nothing can help so far.